# Bluetooth phone, can I find cell carrier?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

After connecting to a cell phone via bluetooth, is there a way to find out what cell carrier (AT&T, Tmobile, etc.) the phone is using?  This would need to work with any bluetooth phone on any carrier.

I'll be using the Microsoft® Surface® Bluetooth Connect Code Sample - SDK 2.0 to connect the phone.

Comment: Reckon that would depend on the availability of a [Bluetooth profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) that actually exposes that information, and the phones' and SDK's support for it. Not sure if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is not possible in any way. and as @Dan J said it depends on the profile and the way it is implemented by the device at hand.